# What is the antonym for darker skin?

Tags: grammar

> My baby was born with fair skin but has become ***darker*** now.
>
> My baby was born with dark skin but has become ***lighter*** now.

What is the antonym for darker skin? Is it *lighter*?

Comment: In your example you use _dark_ -> _darker_. Why not _fair_ -> _fairer_ (or _light_ -> _lighter_)?

Answer (score 4):

Lighter skin is used commonly. It's used also in [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_skin_color) about human skin colour. ("Females evolved to have **lighter** skin so their bodies absorb more calcium." etc.)